# Drupal 7.12 - how do I enable a WYSIWYG editor within the Wysiwyg templates area when creating a new Wysiwyg template?

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I've enabled the [Wysiwyg](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) and [Wysiwyg API template plugin](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_template) modules within a Drupal 7.12 installation.

I've subsequently installed CKEditor 3.6.2.7275 and configured the Wysiwyg profiles for Filtered HTML, and Full HTML to use CKEditor leaving the setting for Plain text set to 'no editor'.

What I want to do is make it so an administrator can use CKEditor when creating new Wysiwyg templates.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

I want an admin to be able to use full or filtered HTML via CKEditor.

Can anyone help me to enable a WYSIWYG editor within the WYSIWYG templates area when creating a new WYSIWYG template?

Comment: Questions should be understandable without reading the text from another question; if the question you linked is deleted, this question would not be clear.

Comment: There's a patch for this here - http://drupal.org/node/1816564. We'll be committing it to the module very soon.

Comment: I am closing this question, as the module now allows to do what described in the question.